# How to set Error Messages for External Form Validation, CodeIgniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation, error-handling

I'm writing my own **custom form validation class** which extends from `CI_Form_validation`.

I'm curious how CodeIgniter sets its own form validation error messages. I don't see `set_message` in `CI_Form_validation`.

Let me know you need more clarification?

Comment: Have you read through here http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it. Will post the answer here in case someone else is asking...

1. Create a `form_validation_lang.php` inside the
   **application/language/english** folder.
2. Then add a `$lang` associative array who index is the name of your
       validation function prefixed with `form_validation_`. E.g. if
       validation function is `valid_date`, it will look like this:
       `$lang['form_validation_valid_date'] = 'The {field} field must
       contain a valid date.';`

The lang file will be loaded automatically by CodeIgniter if you extend from `CI_Form_validation`.